# How to change ANTLR2 to ANTLR3

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

I am developing a practice problem in Java with ANTLR 3.4. The instructions that are given us in ANTLR 2.7 and change with respect to version 3. I found pages show some differences, but not those that seek.

In ANTLR 2.7 MiToken can load a class like this:

```
analex.setTokenObjectClass ("MiToken")**
```

What would be the equivalent in ANTLR 3.4? This option does not exist in that version.

Comment: Many classes in v2 were removed from v3, so chances are there is no 1-on-1 equivalent. Some more context would help (although 4 up-voters may disagree with me: they apparently find your question clear enough, but didn't take the trouble to post an answer...). How are you using `setTokenObjectClass(String)`? What is it supposed to do? (the [old v2 docs](http://www.antlr2.org/javadoc/antlr/CharScanner.html#setTokenObjectClass(java.lang.String)) didn't help much)

Answer (score 1):

In ANTLR 3.4 the method setTokenObjectClass(Sting), does not exists. You should look to that page (is a wiki of ANTLR 3.4):

http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1844

We are using the same instructions PDFs, you use C# as target language, but we use Java as target language. I can get it done because other student in the same class find the name of the method to override (the method´s name to override in ANTLR v3.4 is emit().